# Autofac trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm new to using Autofac and Dependency injection and have been reading a lot on it. I'm getting an error message:"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Evaluate.DivisionsController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Evaluate.Services.DivisionService service' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Evaluate.Services.DivisionService)'."

I'm sure my issue is in the syntax I'm using for the configuration.

Here is my configuration in global.asax

```
//Autofac Configuration
            var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();


            //builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new EFModule());

            var container = builder.Build();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

My EFModule:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)).As(typeof(IApplicationDbContext)).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<UserProvider>().As<IUserProvider>().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<DivisionService>().As<IDivisionService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Controller:

```
 private DivisionService _divisionService;

        public DivisionsController(DivisionService service)
        {
            _divisionService = service;
        }
```

Division Service:

```
public class DivisionService : BaseService<Division>, IDivisionService
    {

        //private IApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DivisionService(IApplicationDbContext context)
            :base(context)
        {

        }
```

ApplicationDBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        private IUserProvider _user;

        public ApplicationDbContext(IUserProvider user)
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            _user = user;
        }
```

User Provider class:

```
public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
    {
        public string GetApplicationUserName()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You registered `DivisionsService` as `IDivisionsService`, but you're trying to inject `DivisionsService`.  `DivisionsService` is not registered as itself, so you can't inject that.

Comment: I changed it to builder.RegisterType<IDivisionService>().As<DivisionService>().InstancePerRequest(), but now I'm getting an error on builder.Build();  'The type 'Evaluate.Services.Contracts.IDivisionService' is not assignable to service 'Evaluate.Services.DivisionService'.'

Comment: I think it has something to do wtih the Generic type on the base service

Comment: You have them backwards.  You register a `DivisionsService` as an `IDivisionsService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.  The IDivisionService wasn't inheriting from the IBaseService